# How can i show an image 3 minutes after the home page appears?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have an image that can take me to another page but 3 minutes after my main page appears. I made my javascrip code in another file. but actually dosen't work!

```
<head>
<title> FASHION </title>
<script src="reduc.js" ></script>
</head>
<body > 

<div class="coupon">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Reduction</h3>
  </div>

  <a href="qcm.html" >
  <img src="imagesreduction.jpg" alt="img" style="width:100%;" 
id="yourImageId" style="display: none" /> </a>
  <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
    <h2><b>40% OFF YOUR PURCHASE</b></h2> 

 </div>
 </div>
```

This my javascript code:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
document.getElementById('yourImageId').display('block'); }, 3 * 60 * 
1000);
```

Comment: document.getElementById('yourImageId').style.display= 'block'

Comment: May I ask why anyone stays on your page for 3min?

Comment: Anyone can stay on my page for hours .. Why not? it's a website and girls especially are interested to stay on the page. The idea is after 3 minutes a reduction image will appear , anyone can get it if he answers some questions that he can know them easy when he checks my website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('yourImageId').style.display = 'block';
}, 3 * 60 * 1000);
```

```css
#yourImageId {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Reduction</h3>
  </div>
  <a href="qcm.html" >
    <img src="imagesreduction.jpg" alt="img" id="yourImageId"/></a>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
      <h2><b>40% OFF YOUR PURCHASE</b></h2> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it's help.

Answer (score -1):

'an image that can take me to another page' on click?

```
window.onload = funciton() {   
 document.getElementById('yourImageId').style.display = 'block';

 setTimeout(() => {
 document.getElementById('yourImageId').onclick = () => 
 location.replace("LINK"));
 }
}
```

Click event on the image will work in 3 minutes after page appears

Comment: He already has a link on a hidden image - all that is needed is correct syntax to show the image after 3 minutes. Voted to close as `typo-type` question